# JButton does not return the right text value

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a problem regarding JButtons. I have a GridLayout of 20x20 JButtons. I want to get the value of a single button when I click on it. (x.getText()).

The *sout* prints the **bottom right** value only, no matter what button I click.

If I click the **top left** button it prints 19. The value I want to get back in this case is 0.

[image]

My code below.

```
public class MainFrame extends Frame implements MouseListener{

JButton button;

public MainFrame() {

    setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    addComponents();

}

private void addComponents(){

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
    JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20, 20));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("test");
    top.add(label);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j ++){
            button = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            button.addMouseListener(this);
            center.add(button);
        }
    }

    mainPanel.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(mainPanel);

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    System.out.println(button.getText());

} 
// Also implements multiple other methods from the interface, but irrelevant for my question.
```

New code (working code):

```
public class MainFrame extends Frame {

public MainFrame() {

    setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    addComponents();

}



private void addComponents(){

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
    JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20, 20));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("test");
    top.add(label);

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = e.getActionCommand();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    };


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j ++){
            JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            button.addActionListener(listener);
            center.add(button);
        }
    }

    mainPanel.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(mainPanel);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a MouseListener on a JButton since by doing this, your button will not respond to space bar presses if it has focus, and also if you disable the button, your MouseListener will still work, which is not correct behavior.

Instead use an ActionListener, a single one is all you need, one that is added to each and every button, and get the action command from the ActionEvent parameter.

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = e.getActionCommand();
    }

}

// add listener to all buttons in a for loop
```

Comment: 1+ for using a single listener, however the action command could later differ from the displayed text, so should you do as @dic19 said it in his comment ?

Answer (score 4):

Look at your code, you only have a single attribute `button` which value is printed in your `mouseClicked` method, so nothing surprising here.

Each button must have its own listener, so remove your attribute and use this code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
     for (int j = 0; j < 20; j ++){
         final JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
         button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
             @Override
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(button.getText());
             }
         });
         center.add(button);
     }
 }
```

You can also use an `ActionListener` instead of a `MouseAdapter`.

Comment: 1+ but... 1) Not need to declare `button` as final. 2) Cast the source of the event as `JButton` and print its text, i.e.: `((JButton)e.getSource()).getText()`. 3) Agree with `ActionListener`.

Comment: 1 ActionListener is all that is needed.

Comment: @dic19 Do you know why final is no longer required when using a local variable in the definition of an anonymous class ? I remember a couple of times when I have had to do this

Comment: Of course `final` is needed if you are going to refer to the variable from within the context of an anonymous inner class. But point 2 means "don't use the variable but use the API instead: `e.getSource()`" :)

Comment: @dic19 I mean, it still compiles when I remove final whereas I have always thought it was required

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an array of buttons then loop it to declare all buttons and to add action listener

Comment: `JButton [][] buttons = new JButton [20][20];` and by using for loop you can declare each button --> `for(int i=0; i<buttons.length();i++){for(int j=0; j<buttons[i].length();j++){ buttons[i][j] = new Button(); }}` then you have an 2d array of buttons you can easily put listeners just by looping this 2d array...